# How to create multi column table header which stay on ipad

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard

I've a class subclassed from UITableView using storyboard but i would like to customerize the tableview as per the attached image. Any Idea how can i achieve it?

thanks for your help.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can alternatively add UILabels to a UIView then simply add that UIView as a subview of your UITableView. Just pass in a negative Y coordinate when you add your UIView during the CGRectMake();

Then you should be set, the table header will scroll with the UITableView.

```
// for table header that scrolls with the table
[myTableView addSubview:tableHeaderView];
```

If you don't want the table header to scroll with the table, then rather than add the UIView to your UITableView, you can add your UIView as a subview of the view controller's view, i.e. at the same level as your UITableView:

```
// for non scrolling table header
[self.view addSubview:myTableView];
[self.view addSubview:tableHeaderView];
```